# Simple Cartesian to Polar Coordinates method

Tags: c#, wpf, trigonometry

Trying to convert some Cartesian to Polar coordinates. Not a mathematician. Start and End values are degrees. Does this make sense?

```
Point outerScreenPointBefore = CartesianToPolar(Start, End);
```

The converter method:

```
 private Point CartesianToPolar(double x, double y)
    {
        x = Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y + y));
        y = Math.Atan2(y, x);

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: You should google "convert cartesian to polar".

Comment: `Start` and `End` are not degrees because they are not angles. Should be `y*y` not `y+y`. `Point` to store polar co-ordinates, really?

Comment: Just realised the map is in Cartesian therefore I've written a method polar-Cartesian:  private Point PolarToCartesian(double radius, double angle)
        {
            double x = radius*Math.Cos(angle);
            double y = radius*Math.Sin(angle); 
        
            return new Point(x, y);
        } Most maths in my previous job was ++1...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly. When you do

```
y = Math.Atan2(y, x);
```

, x has already been given a new value in the previous line:

```
x = Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
```

So, you need to calculate both values before you assign them:

```
double radius = Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
double angle = Math.Atan2(y, x);
return new Point(radius, angle);
```

Polar coordinates don't use the notation x and y, but r and θ, so the meaning may not be clear to someone who reads your code.
You might want to create a new struct with properties Radius and Angle.

Comment: This is actually wrong, the radius is calculated like this x = Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y * y));

Comment: I hadn't even noticed :)